# How to fade out after hover is done using CSS

Tags: css, hover, tumblr, tumblr-themes

So the hashtags in my tumblr theme shows when hover.
the hashtags fade in and show when hover, but as soon as the courser moves out of the region it changes back without any effect. 
How can I have an effect for to fade out the hashtags?

```
 .posts:hover .tags {
opacity:1;
-moz-transition-duration:1s;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
-o-transition-duration:1s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `transition-duration` is applied to element when `:hover` is applied which makes the fade out not work. so move `transition-duration` to `.tags` like below

```
/* default CSS; when :hover is not triggered */
.posts .tags {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
       -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
         -o-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;
}
/* When :hover is triggered */
.posts:hover .tags {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Well, I followed the criteria you have posted for CSS rules.